# How to collect both full lines, and matching part of line?

Tags: awk, grep, paste

Is it possible to output both the `full line` and the `matched parts` of some line?

Suppose I have this input

```
low [ 0]: 0xffff0000 Interesting description A
hi  [ 0]: 0xffff00a0 Interesting description B
low [ 1]:     0x5000 Interesting description C
hi  [ 1]:     0x6000 Interesting description D
...
hi  [15]:   0x806000 ...
```

And I would like to extract the hex value as an interesting part, and then the full line as well. I have used paste and 2 grep commands, but it feels really bulky and I would like to avoid process substitution (`<()`). This is what I got:

```bash
paste -d'\n' <(grep    '0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*' "$file") \
             <(grep -o '0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*' "$file")
```

What's a more, to-the-point way of doing this? I was thinking about awk, but not sure if it's possible to easily grab the matching part and print that (`???` below):

```c
/0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*/ { print $0 ; print ??? }
```

---

Example output:

```
low [ 0]: 0xffff0000 Interesting description A
0xffff0000 
hi  [ 0]: 0xffff00a0 Interesting description B
0xffff00a0 
low [ 1]:     0x5000 Interesting description C
0x5000 
hi  [ 1]:     0x6000 Interesting description D
0x6000 
...
hi  [15]:   0x806000 ...
0x806000
```

Comment: If your real input doesn't contain a line thats `...` then don't add such a line to your sample input/output. It adds no value and just makes it less clear and harder to copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any awk:

```
awk 'match($0,/0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*/) {print $0; print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

With GNU awk:

```
gawk 'match($0,/0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*/,arr) {print $0; print arr[0]}' file
```

You might consider replacing `0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*` with `0x[[:xdigit:]]+`

Comment: Thanks I found RLENGTH, but I didn't make the connection that I could use match in the "condition" part of the script. I was too much looking for something like this* `awk '/0x[0-9a-zA-Z]*/ {print $0; print PMATCH}' file` (which doesn't exist!)

Comment: @Moberg note steeldrivers' suggestion to use `[[:xdigit:]]` but if you don't do that then it'd be `[0-9a-fA-F]`, not `[0-9a-zA-Z]` to match hex digits in locales that behave as you apparently want (YMMV in some locales).

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do this using `sed`:

```bash
sed -e '/.*\(0x[[:xdigit:]]*\).*/!d' -e p -e 's//\1/' file
```

This first discards all lines that do not contain a hexadecimal number in the `0xnnnn...` format. If a line is not discarded, it prints the unmodified line and replaces it with only the hexadecimal number before it's outputted again.

The last step re-uses the regular expression used in the first editing expression, which means we may use `\1` to replace whatever is matched (the whole line) with the substring captured by the parenthesized subexpression (the hexadecimal number).

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{r=$0; sub(/[^:]+/,""); print r ORS $2}' file
low [ 0]: 0xffff0000 Interesting description A
0xffff0000
hi  [ 0]: 0xffff00a0 Interesting description B
0xffff00a0
low [ 1]:     0x5000 Interesting description C
0x5000
hi  [ 1]:     0x6000 Interesting description D
0x6000
hi  [15]:   0x806000 ...
0x806000
```

I assume that `...` line from your question doesn't really exist in your input so I removed it.